# How to have if, else nested tree continue working through the remaining else if’s…

Tags: c++

I have a mini program I’m working on for class. The program is of correct syntax. Logically I cannot get the program to compute the remaining data after it completes the first else if statement that it matches.
I am subtracting numbers from each (a  >=  b) at each else if, the remaining value I am then assigning to a variable temp and using (temp >= c), rinse and repeat till value is zero. Each else if, will assign a char ‘A’ – ‘Z’ depending on the scenario. The problem I am having is it will meet one of the first else if’s but will not continue working the remaining else-ifs. I know this is standard of how if, else works. My question is how would I go about getting the remaining else ifs examined after the first one checks out. Is the only solution to use a switch function? Is there no way I can use if else and have each else checked/passed till my value = 0?

Comment: Please post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You can't - as you said, that's how `else` works. If you want to have subsequent `if` statements evaluated irregardless, don't put them into `else`.

Comment: This *might* be possible using a `case` statement, but without a code example it's impossible to determine if this is applicable here. Please edit  your question and include the code you're talking about. Thanks.

Comment: As has been pointed out, you cannot accomplish this using `else if` because as soon as one is true then the remaining `else if` will be ignored. It would be a lot easier to produce a working example if you posted your code

Answer (score 0):

Just forget using else if, use a chain of if statements instead. For example:

```
bool isThisThree(int number, string &message)
{
    if(number == 1)
        message = "No, it's a one!";
    if(number == 2)
        message = "No, it's a two!";
    if(number == 3) {
        message = "Yes!";
        return true;
    }
    if(number == 4)
        message = "No, it's a four!";
    if(number == 5)
        message = "No, it's a five!";
    return false;
}
```

In this example, the if statements will be examined one by one until the function hits a return statement.